# Why does this spell give the caster full hp?

Tags: java, bukkit

I run a server with my custom spells plugin. This function below is a single spell. What it should do, is deal 2 hearts to anything it hits, and heal the caster 2 hearts (for each target hit). However, it always sets the caster to ten hearts!

```
public void onPlayerInteractBlockLifeSteal(final Player player) {
    if (worldChecker(player)){
            if (player.getFoodLevel() > 12){
                List<Block> targets = player.getLineOfSight((Set)null, 20);
                float pathway = 0;
                for (final Block target : targets){
                    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MagictgCraft.that, new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            int count = 0;
                            if (target.getType() != Material.AIR){
                                player.getWorld().playSound(target.getLocation(), Sound.SUCCESSFUL_HIT, 10, 1);
                            }
                            while (count < 5){
                                player.getWorld().playEffect(target.getLocation().clone().add(0.5,0.5,0.5), Effect.WITCH_MAGIC, 10);
                                player.getWorld().playEffect(target.getLocation().clone().add(0.5,0.5,0.5), Effect.SMOKE, 10);
                                count = count + 1;
                            }
                            List<Entity> victims = (List<Entity>) target.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(target.getLocation(),1,1,1);
                            for (Entity victim2 : victims){
                                if (victim2 instanceof LivingEntity){
                                    LivingEntity victim = (LivingEntity) victim2;
                                    if (victim != player){
                                        victim.damage(4,player);
                                        double health = player.getHealth();
                                        health = health + 4;
                                        if (health > 20){
                                            health = 20;
                                        }
                                            player.setHealth(health);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },(long) pathway);
                    pathway = (float) (pathway + 0.5);
                }
                int manaused = player.getFoodLevel();
                manaused = manaused - 12;
                player.setFoodLevel(manaused);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see any problems?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Block> targets = player.getLineOfSight((Set)null, 20);

for (final Block target : targets)
```

Here this loop calls the Runnable as many times as the amount of blocks in sight. Therefore, they are healed multiple times on every cast and naturally hit the cap of ten hearts, because you set such a wide line of sight.